# How to set the extent of a PostGIS geography table?

Tags: postgis, extents, geography-data-type

I have multiple `geography` tables in PostGIS database. All of them have extents of `(-180,-90;180,90)`, probably in their metadata, which makes editing difficult. I'd like to set the extent to exactly the bounding box of them, but I can't find any command to alter them.

Extents are viewed in QGIS by right clicking the layer and click *Properties*, then click *Info* tab.

**How do I set the extents to exactly the bounding boxes of my `geography` tables?**

Comment: I do not know your purpose, but take a look at "CHECK" constraint.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: in short, you can't; the `GEOGRAPHY` data type reqires the full spherical 'extent' for all implicit calculations. this datatype is not ecactly meant for GIS based visualization, but for precise trigonometric calculations; load and view your tables as `GEOMETRY`s, calculate in-DB with `GEOGRAPHY`.